# Electrical Circuit for Detached Shed 200 ft

Tags: circuit-breaker, subpanel, shed

Would it be acceptable to run a branch circuit from a panel to a detached storage shed that will be approximately 200 feet away, instead of a feeder with sub-panel and grounding rods?

The circuit will power 4 low current draw LED wall packs (<1A each), and possibly one wall receptacle that would be used for a battery tender.

Planning direct burial 10/2 with ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, you can run a single branch circuit to a structure

Considering you only need a single branch circuit there, you *can* run a single branch circuit out to your shed with say 10AWG for hot/neutral/ground, or hot/hot/neutral/ground if you want to run a multi-wire branch circuit.  The exception to 250.32(A) means you won't need a ground rod at the shed as the equipment grounding conductor to the main structure is a sufficient grounding means for a single branch circuit.

You'll need a disconnecting means at the shed to satisfy 225.31; however, this can be a simple light switch in a weatherproof box or just inside the shed, nothing fancier is needed for a single branch circuit.  You'll want the receptacle to be GFCI-protected, by the way, due to the fact this is an unfinished space.

### However, I'd trench in a fat conduit anyway

Renting a trencher for the day isn't cheap.  Schedule 80 PVC is, even in say 2 or 3" diameter.  This means that while you're digging, you might as well put in a fat PVC conduit to the shed even if you're only running a few 10AWG THHNs in it, instead of using a direct bury cable, as the conduit will make expansion way easier.  Besides, Schedule 80 is going to hold up to an inadvertent excavator encounter better than a UF cable anyhow.

Comment: Why not install a multiwire branch circuit?  Also, don't forget the GFCI protection.

Answer (score 1):

I ran 12 /3 about 100 ft. to a shed without sub-panel or ground rod ;  it hasn't killed me in 15 years. I did use plastic conduit which I recommend and GFI. I use up to 500 watts ( 110 V).

Comment: Do you have a disconnect out there?

Comment: Not at the shed ; I put a small panel in the garage with a disconnect. I did not read code , but I would never put any electric outside without GFI .

Answer (score 0):

You're barely pulling 2 amps. 10/2, 10/3 branch circuit will do fine.

Do you hear that? Here come the code book copy/pasters.... The afci's!! Where are the afci's?!?!!!!  ;)

Comment: Garages and sheds are exempt from AFCI protection, but not GFCI protection.

Comment: Hahahahahahaaa! +1 for that!